# Modificacion de texto en Notepad++

Tags: edittext, notepad++

Tengo un archivo txt que es la exportación de una bd de Access.
En el mismo cada línea es un registro de la bd en el cual los campos están separados por "|" y cada línea termina en un salto de línea "\n"
El problema es que uno de los campos también tiene saltos de línea "\n" en su contenido, lo cual hace que al importar a MySQL me tome ese salto de línea como el fin de un registro rompiendo toda la base de datos.

Dado que cada registro arranca con un número (id) había pensado que podría eliminar todos aquellos saltos de línea que no sigan de un número, quizás con regex se pueda hacer esto.

Al final les dejo una imagen donde resalto el problema con una flecha roja y un fragmento del txt para que tengan para hacer pruebas. El problema es que no sabria como hacer eso con Notepad++

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda

[image: Fragmento]

**Fragmento del archivo txt para hacer pruebas**

50637||nc|nc|faros|Rocha|Cabo Santa María / La Paloma|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|LC1981|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1981/09/28 / IHA.Carp.1517/5|0|El faro del Cabo Santa María tuvo dos torres como la que hoy conocemos. Una de ellas se derrumbó el 31 de mayo de 1872 cuando estaba en construcción.
50638||nc|nc|faros|Rocha|Cabo Santa María / La Paloma|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|RPV1977|FA2012|D."El Día" / Mdeo.1974/09/07 / IHA.Carp.1398/8|0|Historia de la construcción del Faro de La Paloma. Cabo Santa María (Rocha).
50639||nc|nc|faros|Rocha|Cabo Santa María / La Paloma|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|RM1977|FA2012|D."El Día" / Mdeo.1974/09/06 / IHA.Carp.1377/1|0|Centenario del faro de Santa María.
50640|g|nc|nc|faros|Rocha|Cabo Santa María / La Paloma|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|sd|FA2012|MAESO,C.M."El Uruguay a través de un siglo" / Mdeo.1910 / p.268|0|Exterior.
50641||nc|nc|faros|Colonia|Colonia|nc|nc|nc|nc|1857|nc|FCH1981|FA2012|IHA.Ft.2123-501-2680|0|
50642||nc|nc|faros|Colonia|Colonia|nc|nc|nc|La Farola|nc|nc|RPV1977|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1977/09/25 / IHA.Carp.1459/8|0|Artículo periodístico sobre el Faro de Colonia y sus anteriores destinos. (artículo incompleto).
50643||nc|nc|feria|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MMU1987|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1987/08/17 / IHA.Carp.1611/11|0|Sobre las relaciones entre la Agrupación de Feriantes Municipales y de Tristán Narvaja con la Intendencia Municipal de Montevideo.
50644|g|nc|nc|feria|Montevideo|Montevideo|Cordón|Tristán Narvaja|nc|nc|nc|nc|NC1987|FA2012|D."El Día".Supl.dominical / Mdeo.1968/07/28 / IHA.Carp.Nº1835|0|Artículo sobre la feria dominical de la calle Tristán Narvaja.
50645|g|nc|nc|feria|Montevideo|Montevideo|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|AT1991|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1991/11/10 / IHA.Carp.1735/5|0|Información sobre las ferias dominicales de Montevideo. Incluye una lista de las ferias y su ubicación.
50646||nc|nc|feria / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|Ganado,de|nc|nc|SRV1965|FA2012|IHA.Carp.939/3a9|0|DEFFONTAINES,Pierre."Routes de bétail et types de foires en Uruguay". "Caminos de tropas y tipos de ferias en el Uruguay". Tomado de los "Cahiers d'Outre-mer" / 1951/04-06 / Nº14
50647|g|nc|nc|feria|Durazno|Sarandí del Yí|nc|nc|nc|Ganado,de|1909|nc|AM1987|FA2012|IHA.Ft.14416|0|Vista general de las construcciones de la "Sociedad Exposición Feria de Sarandí del Yí". Fotografía donada por el Dr. José C. Williman.
50648||nc|nc|feria|Montevideo|Montevideo|nc|nc|nc|Industrial|1969/02-05|nc|MM1969|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1969/04/13 / IHA.Carp.1211/7|0|Entre el 10/02/1970 y el 31/03/1970 se realizará una Feria Mundial de la Industria en Montevideo, en el Puerto, en el llamado Muelle de Escala.
50649||nc|nc|feria|Montevideo|Montevideo|nc|nc|nc|Industria,de la|1970/02|nc|MM1969|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1969/08/27 / IHA.Carp.1228/37|0|Se inaugurará en febrero de 1970 la Feria Mundial de la Industria en Montevideo. La ANP. ha proporcionado un muelle frente a Pérez Castellano y Maciel.
50650|g|nc|nc|feria|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|Internacional|1969|nc|MM1969|FA2012|D."El Día" / Mdeo.1969/09/16 / IHA.Carp.1228/41|0|Fotos y nota de los "stands" uruguayos en las ferias de Padua y Leipzig, realizadas en el 69.
50651||nc|nc|feria|Montevideo|Montevideo|nc|nc|nc|Nacional de Libros y Grabados|nc|nc|MMU1987|FA2012|D."El Día" / Mdeo.1987/08/31 / IHA.Carp.1611/17|0|La Feria Nº28 no se realizará como es habitual en el predio de Av.Rivera y Bulevar Artigas, sino en la Plaza Gomensoro.
50652||nc|nc|fortificación / generalidades históricas / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MM1973|FA2012|R."Revista del Instituto Histórico y Geográfico del Uruguay" / Mdeo.1926 / T.V.Nº2.p.685|0|ARREDONDO,Horacio (hijo)."Fortificaciones de Montevideo. El Portón de San Pedro".
50653||nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MM1972|FA2012|R."Revista de la Sociedad Amigos de la Arqueología" / Año.1957.T.XV.p.382 / IHA.Bca.|0|BORDEJE,Federico."Extractos informativos"
50654||nc|nc|fortificación / generalidades históricas / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|FCH1982|FA2012|IHA.Carp.1532/151a197|0|CAMPOS,Alfredo R."Breve reseña histórica del servicio de ingeniería y arquitectura militar" / Mdeo.1978
50655||nc|nc|fortificación / generalidades históricas / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|OM1956|FA2012|R."Revista del Instituto Histórico y Geográfico del Uruguay" / Mdeo. / TomoVII.Año1930.p.175-194 / TomoVIII.Año1931.p.139-256|0|CORTES ARTEAGA,Mariano."Fortificaciones de Montevideo durante la Guerra Grande (1843-1851)".
CORTES ARTEAGA,Mariano."Organización defensiva de Montevideo durante la Guerra Grande (1843-1851)".
50656||nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MM1972|FA2012|IHA.Bca.|0|GARCIA,Flavio,A."La guardia de San Nicolás de Bari".Boletín Histórico del Estado Mayor del Ejército / Mdeo.1958 / Nº75-75.p.13
50657||nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|Siglos XVII-XVIII|nc|MM1974|FA2012|IHA.Carp.1343 / fichero de investigación|0|LUCCHINI,Aurelio."Exposición general sobre la obra arquitectónica-militar realizada durante los siglos XVII y XVIII en el territorio que hoy ocupa la República Oriental del Uruguay". Trabajo de investigación Nº71.
50658||nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MM1972|FA2012|R."Revista de la Sociedad Amigos de la Arqueología" / Año1931.T.V.p.157 / IHA.Bca.|0|SEIJO,Carlos."La Guardia de San Antonio".
50659|g|nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MM1970|FA2012|ZAPATERO,Juan Manuel."Las fortificaciones de Cartagena de Indias. Estudio asesor para su restauración" / Madrid.1969|0|El ejemplar consultado pertenece al Arq. Antonio Cravotto. La obra tiene excelente y abundante material gráfico.
50660||nc|nc|fortificación|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|1904|nc|MA1967|FA2012|CORTES ARTEAGA,Mariano."Los Ingenieros Militares en nuestro pasado" / Mdeo.1934 / pp.96a99|0|Obras de defensa y reconstrucciones realizadas durante 1904 por ingenieros militares en Colonia, Paysandú, Río Negro, Rivera, Florida, etc.
50661||nc|nc|fortificación|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|OM1957|FA2012|IHA.Carp.39/39yss.|0|Leyes de Indias sobre "Fábricas y fortificaciones" y "Castillos y fortalezas".
50662||nc|nc|fortificación|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|RAL1957|FA2012|FURLONG,Guillermo."Arquitectos Argentinos durante la dominación hispánica" / BsAs.1946 / p.140|0|Teorías de Vauban.
"…las doctrinas de Vauban se habían popularizando en todas las escuelas militares de España a fines del siglo XVII o a principios del XVIII. Mucho antes que los Borbones ocuparan el trono hispano, habían los militares hispanos abandonado las doctrinas de Fernándes de Villareal, de Alonso de Cepeda y de Julio C. Ferrufino, atendiéndose, en un todo, al libro del Jesuíta José Cassani, cuya publicación se realizó en 1705, aunque era ya popular desde muchos años antes, así por las enseñanzas de Cassani en la cátedra como por las copias manuscritas que corrían de mano en mano……………………………………………………………
"Escuela Militar de fortificaciones ofensiva y defensiva" rotúlase el libro de este Jesuíta, y su idea fundamental era el adagio, entonces vulgar que una ciudad sitiada conforme a los métodos de Vauban era una ciudad tomada y una ciudad defendida según las normas de Vauban era una ciudad inexpugnable…………….
Entre las innovaciones de Vauban hay que mencionar la construcción de las llamadas paralelas, líneas extensas de trincheras de amplio frente hacia la plaza, el tiro a rebote y los caballos de trincheras. Estas eran obras dominantes destinadas a desalojar al agresor del camino cubierto".
50663||nc|nc|fortificación|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|sd|FA2012|HAUTECOEUR,L."Histoire de l'architecture classique en France" / París.1948 / ParteI.pp.491 y ss.|0|Teorías de Vauban.
50664||nc|nc|fortificación / puerto|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MMU1987|FA2012|D."El Día" / Mdeo.1987/06/03 / IHA.Carp.1606/12|0|La Embajada de España donará al Cabildo de Montevideo la Exposición de "Puertos y Fortificaciones en América y Filipinas". Muestras geográficas.
50665||nc|nc|fortificación / exposición / puerto|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|nc|MJG1987|FA2012|D."El País" / Mdeo.1967/06/05 / IHA.Carp.1602/2|0|El Cabildo de Montevideo recibe donación del gobierno español de los paneles que integraron la exposición "Puertos y Fortificaciones de América y Filipinas". Consiste en gráficas que ilustran los diferentes momentos de la colonización del centinente americano.
50666||nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|Montevideo|Montevideo|Cerro|nc|nc|Artigas,Gral.|nc|nc|AB1961|FA2012|F.de A.Bca.|0|ARREDONDO,Horacio."La Fortaleza del Cerro" / Mdeo.1944
50667||nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|Montevideo|Montevideo|Cerro|nc|nc|Artigas,Gral.|nc|nc|MM1972|FA2012|R."Revista de la Sociedad Amigos de la Arqueología" / Año.1938-41.T.IX.p.185 / IHA.Bca.|0|ARREDONDO,Horacio."La Fortaleza del Cerro. Su restauración"
50668|g|nc|nc|fortificación / bibliografía|Montevideo|Montevideo|Cerro|nc|nc|Artigas,Gral.|nc|nc|JC1959|FA2012|Apartado de la Revista de la Sociedad de Amigos de la Arqueología / T.IX.Año1938-39 / IHA.Carp.424/31a57|0|ARREDONDO,Horacio."La Fortaleza del Cerro. Su restauración".